# Same data structure returned from javascript and python behaves differently in d3.js

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js

When I am using this data structure from a javascript source file:

```
var data = [{'x': 100, 'y': '65'}, 
  {'x': 122, 'y': '57'}, 
  {'x': 144, 'y': '101'}, 
  {'x': 166, 'y': '87'}, 
  {'x': 188, 'y': '8'}, 
  {'x': 210, 'y': '180'}, 
  {'x': 232, 'y': '132'}, 
  {'x': 257, 'y': '190'}, 
  {'x': 276, 'y': '210'}, 
  {'x': 298, 'y': '150'}]
```

and `alert` the data in my main file it shows:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

also it works fine with :

```
alert(d3.max(data,function(d) { return d.count;}))
```

But when I using a python as a source file and returns this :

```
 data = [{'x': 100, 'y': '65'}, 
  {'x': 122, 'y': '57'}, 
  {'x': 144, 'y': '101'}, 
  {'x': 166, 'y': '87'}, 
  {'x': 188, 'y': '8'}, 
  {'x': 210, 'y': '180'}, 
  {'x': 232, 'y': '132'}, 
  {'x': 257, 'y': '190'}, 
  {'x': 276, 'y': '210'}, 
  {'x': 298, 'y': '150'}]

abc=json.dumps(data)
print data
```

The alert shows also the same:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

But this does not work:

```
alert(d3.max(data,function(d) { return d.count;}))
```

Here is my entire code

```
function add_py()
{
 var count = $( "#count" ).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "abc.py",
        data: {'count': count},
        datatype:"script",
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
        var data= JSON.parse(response);

        showGraph(data);
        }, // success closed
        error:function(xhr,err)
        {
            alert("Error connecting to server, please contact system administator.");
        }
    })//ajax closed
}


function  showGraph(de)  {
  alert(de) 
  var mySVG = d3.select("body").append("svg");

  mySVG 
.attr("width", 500) 
.attr("height", 500);

  var heightScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, 963])
.range([0, 400]);

  alert(d3.max(de,function(d) { return d.count;}))
  var heightScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(de,function(d) { return d.count;})])
  .range([0, 400]);

  var myBars = mySVG.selectAll('circle')
.data(de)
.enter()
.append('svg:circle');

  myBars
.attr('r',20);

  myBars
.attr('cx',function(d,i) {return (i * 22) + 100;})
.attr('cy',function(d,i) {return 400 - heightScale(d.count);});

  }
```

I understand a data from js and from python file may behave differently , but how to make python data working same like js data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You have number values for `x` and strings for `y`: it could help if you change them to numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get exactly how are you mixing JavaScript and Python, I'll just assume you are trying to load the `data` object as a string from a Python program (perhaps via a server?). In this case, you need to parse the string and convert it to a JSON object (i.e., an internal JavaScript object) by doing this:

```
data = JSON.parse(data)
```

in your main file.

EDIT: also make sure that your Python program is outputting your dictionary as a valid JSON format, just `print`ing it won't work, you need something like `json.dumps(data)`.

Comment: @ Emanuele Bezzi I edited my code, the alert `alert(d3.max(de,function(d) { return d.count;}))` is not working while data came from python, but worked fine when data came from js

Comment: @ Emanuele Bezzi , Sorry my fault it should be  `alert(d3.max(de,function(d) { return d.x;}))`